# XSD : Unordered list of element that contains xs:any

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an unordered list of elements that contains xs:any , multiple combinations of choice and sequence was tried , they all violate the **"Unique Particle Attribution"**.
My xml is the following :

```
<mall id="Andaal">
    <eff>effRecorder</eff>
    <morr>id</morr>
    <todd>toddCurrentType == toddIdOldType</todd>
    <mall id="donAllId">
        <morr>id</morr>
        <eff>effRecorder</eff>
        <other>QuickCode</other>
        <mall id="mall2Id">
            <eff>TickerChainEff</eff>
            <morr>SourceId</morr>
            <other>TickerCode</other>
        </mall>
    </mall>
    <mall id="mall2SourceId">
        <eff>Listing2SourceEff</eff>
        <morr>id</morr>
        <other>other2Price</other>
        <other>ExpiryDate</other>
    </mall>
</mall>
```

the xsd code :

```
<xs:element name="mall" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="eff" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="todd" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="morr" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z_]+"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Note that the elements `eff`, `todd` and `morr` can occur in any order, and they can occur deeper in the hierarchy inside another `mall` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XSD 1.0**

Using XSD 1.0 this is not possible. Basically the parser needs to be able to pick up each element and given its current state figure out (unambiguously) which schema element it should use to validate it. It does not support any form of look ahead. By introducing the *any* you are providing ambiguity, the any would match the existing eff,todd,morr elements, this could be resolved by looking ahead, but thats not supported.

So the best you get is this

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7015 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="mall">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="eff" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="todd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="morr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:any minOccurs="0" namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z_]+" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Where the *any* is constrained to be any namespace that is NOT the current targetnamespace. This prevents the ambiguity and everythings OK.

Except....now you have a schema that allows 0-n eff, todd, morr elements. So its far from perfect.

**XSD 1.1**

You can do exactly what you are trying to do using XSD 1.1 using the openContent element.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7015 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="mall">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:openContent mode="interleave">
                <xs:any processContents="lax" />
            </xs:openContent>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="eff" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="todd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="morr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z_]+" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This enforces the cardinality rules placed on eff, todd & morr while allowing you to put any other content in between them i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7015 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<mall xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Schema11.xsd" id="_Mi___XW">
    <OTHER></OTHER>
    <eff>string</eff>
    <OTHER></OTHER>
    <todd>string</todd>
    <OTHER></OTHER>
    <morr>string</morr>
    <OTHER></OTHER>
</mall>
```

The downside is XSD 1.1 is not widley suported yet, Xerces and a few other parsers support it, but not many.

**UPDATE**

Updated to reflect Michael Kay's comments. As Michael points out XSD 1.1 can now resolve the ambiguity between the *any* and the named elements. The result is simpler.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7015 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="mall">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="eff" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="todd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="morr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" />
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z_]+" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Actually you don't need the openContent in XSD 1.1: the schema is OK as is, because an ambiguity between a specific element particle and a wildcard particle is resolved in favour of the specific element.